# A each_item in item function doesn't work. I don't know how to implement nested_item

Tags: python, each

i have a problem. I found this programm and want to work with it. I know that the words in the list will list down under through print but i don't know how exactly it works! You know what nested_item is. I haven't find it so far. Thank you!

```
movies = ["Yeah Buddy", "Light Way Baby", 2006, "It´s awesome", "Hulk Hogan 2008"]
for each_item in movies:
    if isinstance(each_item, list):
        for nested_item in each_item:
            print(nested_item)
    else:
        print(each_item)
```

Comment: If your movies list has nested list inside instead of a string eg.: ["Yeah Buddy", "Light Way Baby", ["More", "Films"]...] and it will print the items in the nested list also line by line..

Answer (score 1):

```
movies = ["Yeah Buddy", "Light Way Baby", 2006, "It´s awesome", "Hulk Hogan 2008"]
```

that creates a list named `movies` with some values.  In this case, all of them are strings or numbers.

```
for each_item in movies:
```

this creates a `for` loop, which iterates once for every element in `movies`.  For each iteration, one of the elements is stored in the variable `each_item`.

```
    if isinstance(each_item, list):
```

This line tests if the variable `each_item` holds a value of type `list` (or an instance of it).  In your test case, there are no lists, so these lines are not executed:

```
        for nested_item in each_item:
            print(nested_item)
```

This loops again through all the items in the list `each_item`, and prints all its elements.

```
    else:
        print(each_item)
```

If the element `each_item` is not a list, these lines print its content.

In short: the program iterates through the items in `movies`, printinv its content if they are not a list, or printing the contents of each element in the inner list otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I will look up for my own in the shell but i think i have understand!

Answer (score 0):

your program checks for the `List in list`

```
movies = ["Yeah Buddy",['YOU','Have','enlighted me'] ,"Light Way Baby", 2006, "It´s awesome", "Hulk Hogan 2008"]
for each_item in movies:
    if isinstance(each_item, list):
        for nested_item in each_item:
            print(nested_item)
    else:
        print(each_item)
```

now your nested_item have the elememts of inner list

given in movies list the second element is a list . so now `isinstance(each_item, list)` returns true and for loop starts printing `'YOU','Have','enlighted me'`

Answer (score 0):

Show it:

```
movies = ["Yeah Buddy", [1, 2, 's'], "Light Way Baby", 2006, "Its awesome", "Hu$
for each_item in movies:
    if isinstance(each_item, list):
        for nested_item in each_item:
            print('-- %s' % nested_item)
    else:
        print(each_item)
```